# How do I turn an array returned from a function (like split) into an array reference?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

Consider this code:

```
@tmp = split(/\s+/, "apple banana cherry");
$aref = \@tmp;
```

Besides being inelegant, the above code is fragile. Say I follow it with this line:

```
@tmp = split(/\s+/, "dumpling eclair fudge");
```

Now `$$aref[1]` is "eclair" instead of "banana".

How can I avoid the use of the temp variable?

Conceptually, I'm thinking of something like

```
$aref = \@{split(/\s+/, "apple banana cherry")};
```

Comment: Functions can't return arrays. `split` returns a list of scalars, just like any sub.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do this if you want an array-ref:

```
my $aref = [ split(/\s+/, "apple banana cherry") ];
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

```
$aref = [split(/\s+/, "apple banana cherry")];
```

Answer (score 2):

While I like mu's answer (and would use that approach first here), keep in mind that variables can be rather easily scoped, even without the use of functions, imagine:

```
my $aref = do {
  my @temp = split(/\s+/, "apple banana cherry");
  \@temp;
};
print join("-", @$aref), "\n";
# with warnings: Name "main::temp" used only once: possible typo at ...
# with strict: Global symbol "@temp" requires explicit package name at ...
print join("-", @temp), "\n";
```

Happy coding.